# Synology DSM 6.1.3 Where are the MariaDB 5 files located

Tags: nas, synology

I'm having the following problem:

My Synology DS216SE doesn't want to install phpBB after I updated MariaDB from version 5 to 10.
The problem here is that strangly phpBB seems to find my MariaDB 5 installation (which is not installed anymore) and wants to import data from it to MariaDB 10. This operation fails, of course.

**Does anyone know where the MariaDB 5 files are located in except the folder "var/packages/MariaDB5" (which is already deleted of course)?**

My NAS has the following configuration:

phpBB version: 3.2.0-0122.

Synology DSM version: DSM 6.1.3-15152 Update 6

Processor: MARVELL Armada 370 88F6707

Processor rate: 800 MHz

Comment: I've forwarded this now to the Synology forum, too: https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=287&t=136665

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution (Even if I still don't know the exact issue): https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=556&t=2441286&p=14906311#p14906311

1. Install both database versions (MariaDB 5 and 10).
2. Import the whole mysql dump from before.
3. Add the same users (root) to both database versions.
4. Install phpBB on Synology package center with the passwords and a user for phpBB with some password.
5. I got an error: Database already exists" --> Dropped database for phpBB in MariaDB10.
6. Install was successful.
7. Uninstalled MariaDB5.
8. The board works again but posting is not possible. (There are some forum posts on this issue already and I will try to find a solution for this, too.)